# Sealed Room Security - Possibility of writing assembled binary code

Tags: malware, programming

Assume the existence of a sealed room, containing a network with a single terminal. You are not allowed to bring in any electronic material into the room. The target machine is running default installation of windows 7 and only has MSOffice installed on of the operating system. The objective is to infect the network with a malware.

Since no electronics are allowed to be brought in, a potential solution was to print out a malware executable in any form, binary or assembly onto a piece of paper. This paper is then allowed to be brought in as it is not electronic in nature. The program would then be transcribed onto the target machine, saved as an executable then executed.

The question is whether this is possible without any additional installations as the network and terminal in question have no other means of input other than through keyboard and mouse.

The objective of this question is to check the existence of any means of code execution by means of a human medium, through purely the keyboard. Security have always been on the subject of preventing portable media to be connected to a secure system to prevent infection. What if the person were to write a malware on the target machine itself? Would it be possible with just the default installation of Windows?

The objective is arbitrary code execution. Not CMD fork bombs.

Means that has been explored:

- debug.exe doesnt ship with windows 7 and therefore we cant type assembly and run against that.
- Using notepad doesnt work as there are null characters on the ASCII table that the keyboard cannot input. This means that we cant write binary in ASCII and save it as a .COM or .EXE
- Even if you are able to, tested by copy pasting an executable opened in notepad to another file, the new file would still not run.

Comment: ....how locked down is the machine?  I mean, you can get (BadUSB'd) thumbdrives that are the size of a microSD card, which you can hide just about anywhere on your person.  Which would certainly be less suspicious than a few hundred sheets of paper...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse For the purposes of this question you can assume the machine is placed inside a sealed cabinet or have all its USB ports hardware disabled.

Comment: If you know a document with malware code is gonna be brought in and still allow it through, may as well let them bring a USB. It's gonna take more time with a piece of paper, but they can just type stuff from the paper in as malware anyway...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If MSOffice is a full installation *including* the macro subsystem, this should be simple. The macro language is also called Visual Basic for Application and is very close to a VB development environment. You now have two options:

- if you have prepared your malware as a VBA script, just type and execute it.
- if you have the hexadecimal dump of your malware executable, it should not be too hard to write a piece of VBA code that translates back hexa values in raw bytes.

A vanilla Windows installation comes with very few tools, few of them allowing to deal with binary data. The only one I can think of is Power Shell. Unfortunately, I am not proficient at it, and cannot know whether it is possible/easy to translate hexadecimal to bytes.

Comment: Windows also executes *.vba and *.js scripts just fine in a default installation. And PowerShell can access all .NET methods.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, it is possible, even without Microsoft Office.

With `echo -n -e "win\x00\x20" > file.exe`, you can `echo` arbritrary binary to a file then later execute it.

`-n` for no newline at end of echo contents
`-e` for escape codes

---

[SSCCE](https://tio.run/##7RzJjt027N6vGORapLUWy/KlgDd9RS5JGiA9NAHay/Trp6JE2bLsJ9pPeZgJ4AMh29RGiqQoWdSnj/9@fXn58vnr96f3357ef3l69@G5MR@eZW1hsKA@PFfcAkOoDgD3qZjwPSknIJW27hvlJVG/0h@e2dG@RPUJjd/a9Xc2YjogXiV11Of6J4l8FN7oPK8pfKUJnojkXSbjo5cx3IOAl3fiZz7fiSflkOXH76zcnMWbYUeGTuAD8KP0JXUxSKcMfxGv7sRzSj6qPJ6kj@fpc@1n6At4dSd@JGSMwpP6J/PvtczzL@DlnXgpCbmWJ/uftm9hsjrX2HxKbvOPMq@TAS/vxAuif6KUPpbQp@6zL68FjMDXPD9@j7YvhtAvCk/ND9z6N8raYGX9AGVpFcrLxPwdnscoj@1rA/zQ/jukMMdBOXify0M@O7cq458F35cnRvRXNhZs@bq@0z4S8sxk3h9I2@e9fbdt9kAb8kXbOgab1r33EUebd7J4Afyw9E@9z8vg2YJuPM75XowYL/Zz6dMG@oTf/LH6@6Pr5/zgPF0Asf4psaM7KNNNhbonPd7ZJ@MhrQO@QR5nt6wMNdw/u7yj/xb0eVVPg3jjcbl6AGYdgfVR63VDYvug80H3XVpn9JcT9ovt6wNlv4FfrPO0hrXOal1G6JdbX5jb9nkz34mT8qs9DTfrb8rsAa9O1n9Sf6Ttv7Y0T4P39dx7730SDuM9LDrjcPbbUHkZgjyT9vKyV@cgfZ2DuF@3jPFy5@xC1Bf4Dv1z9j/6DmMNdlqm@ZLyasevnax8TVgmBseHbqc825Yfb5Qfubelc3krd@0B@kG@p9Hrpob67Xs9IY@hvzwaQ@n9iRr9ZigzNH68@mrtZ0IZh2P4bQ9ngas1Dsa7bxIapadn5n00J/faz6GxDMNcLNH/EIn@BFoMrmtmOsFu2jZY7@vcleNINmFPpbb192bbBvR5qtZ91jf8ZKjDyW8iV1AWbCJVvp@27Qf6NYzttM8DGBczeXsU8yA8myjfhDyWKJOD8s8j1uH4UR/jG8goxbdAc8yfW@OvK@8rwTojlv/ZtrOIH0gj0ANzVyxjrh2URbcXF9cFdIr9cQI6eOKjBxkTZumHs2W2zlas6TvCM7NDA/R5RP6AXWi6hJ4kP/RzkFtdA7/URLzY689GRiP@S@hbg6nyqZMfg99qTKX3AfTo7RXILdhunsrs6PV2gxeLjTIqsle498pj@U3mGyfro5d1oBn6G9Mc@A12EPjN0S6OPa1/jiZou1ueXf/kmg@QwlwyDtH8JbxswbtovXyArLi6kjmuRr1xvBwwDe8TpsbX2Z6wH7Nc5@br3FzL1n4B5Fc1@psD@qg4rzWNfwcfcV477qxnwAbDWIke98cy@5Mskd8m2Q@tE7wctuv3WG86ufW9Y/yQ7s8keJjD43mbSXr/FXS35tE72sWZFwP6YRrndObf2U79m/1gvaafdyf9z0f1P/ifRP9b7XU39F/s9WHy7bn/L5P3mWXnZR/seINt6@DzGO/zg3wBP4Tw/eCc3l9P9/s6teYv21nDgG6GPmr8R@R82tGvD8CfinmUa0@l7Vfr9tVe@zxq32D7fOGVDn5A7b@BroIddv@dMB/sA@sB5w/0nUSgR0Xf0F4ALXJEH6vyOh/wgR8i4g3UP7dVrfsX9z88Bz6l8tkl4zUk8l/xn3y/5IILLrjgggsuuOCCCy644IILLrjgggsuuOCCCy644IILLnjbkInPmIj4PxJYIZ6IL4P/q@7f8a08Y758T8SnsPbA@e5c/ERP0EfEH7GOPp@bbX8oa9/Uy/9rZbb4logfpOL5GDV@RLxOT7VP8E@M5@IDdvufw9eFunngbHH2/DRx3kCUnr9piPIEvqXGnyivK6K8Lhu/qi0rvzobs6M/iuh/fLZrrzxlP02VLw9nJrP8u@BNAxUfWwwqP/8zVegfUPEbjT@rBiA6fzYLaIbzuhBLBOdVFZ4Bh2d3drbGeB6M8wMbF2L/mhvl4LxtM/lUqKXcXIf0Z3xv1l/5OCJRLXW455BGdmSOn9JL7FKIW3JxT3zJN8c0Sn@2zuWL6gGcO9OKeI5ncV2cU4sxkKHeJl/OxVZh/KR7D3xqk1jLdjkHuFtOYyyWWOJQ3HegM9Aj8HnM4JEvt9qBeImZJwL7ZZaYsbNlarNuz50TDmeJ2baPuXwNnt1t5HYsIY2/x3nnPpskTxh/ndSp1vWu@mR8f91YYDqXq/3YuJg6hfkZxtbV@F0jvfx4uVu0uvwhPg/LNO1tOsj8nY8jXPUtGpu5T63Pt5IHs/B6d5xu8QxlponrwzhI1xbyIOjrNT/t@M/spH968P6Su@8nKV2/Uv6zKItnPHp/xOl7O45CoRxv4itO0t8Q9DcU/fJ16U/vr4DYnJU/zg@sjzL0t6XyX5ftD5D0T4Q94GXr@56gXx3xb3P6Xrh@lFT8NS/bHwn4u/c3Hmz/5ESsZyn7R6xPA/5u@aXkn5fh657YDyDKU/sDitgj4g@Wf/LuiI6wp7xsf0cT9DP9WPtH1d8Q90dJXrY/1lL6X52jf0NPKf3TufvQzu7vDwT9rHvd@b9py@g31P5gVTj@hfdPUfhN3O9J@jnx/4lTY1Rov0rL67GMfur@TUHQr3nZHM4K5acVZfRT/@d64n46av/@0frftmXr34H4PzsQc1jxfVOF9HesjP6j9wvefX/go@k3ZfQ7@6OI/1u5@0vl69q/vt3Gyp/5v3n0fsK3av@HVDbNSfqp//v6bdM/UvovDsz/ufth3/j4j6rsPraj9@PebJ9aw6vC9Q/l/@iy8afutwv4Vxt/Aj@aMvrJ8x3EGPBXpn8qHH9O3D8Y8I/yX0vlZ5qI@gT9/yNHvyDoL5b/wv0/Q/j/petTiv5i/4/9YLwo7E@6vzbk6Tev@v/r3dMfT5/@@vbxn/9@@fz17@9/Pv36HN5/@90/vLz8Dw) for Ubuntu (64-bit):

```
echo -n -e "\x7F\x45\x4C\x46\x02\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x3E\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x30\x04\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x68\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x40\x00\x38\x00\x09\x00\x40\x00\x1D\x00\x1C\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x40\x00\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x40\x00\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF8\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF8\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x38\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x38\x02\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x38\x02\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFC\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFC\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x10\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x28\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x30\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x28\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x28\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x28\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x54\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x54\x02\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x54\x02\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x44\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x44\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x50\xE5\x74\x64\x04\x00\x00\x00\xD4\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD4\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD4\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x34\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x34\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x51\xE5\x74\x64\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x52\xE5\x74\x64\x04\x00\x00\x00\x10\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x2F\x6C\x69\x62\x36\x34\x2F\x6C\x64\x2D\x6C\x69\x6E\x75\x78\x2D\x78\x38\x36\x2D\x36\x34\x2E\x73\x6F\x2E\x32\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x47\x4E\x55\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x47\x4E\x55\x00\x2B\x42\xB3\x6D\x6C\x84\xCC\x5B\x46\xD5\xE3\x3D\x3F\xEB\x6D\x1F\xEF\x87\x3D\x09\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x22\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x6C\x69\x62\x63\x2E\x73\x6F\x2E\x36\x00\x70\x75\x74\x73\x00\x5F\x5F\x6C\x69\x62\x63\x5F\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74\x5F\x6D\x61\x69\x6E\x00\x5F\x5F\x67\x6D\x6F\x6E\x5F\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74\x5F\x5F\x00\x47\x4C\x49\x42\x43\x5F\x32\x2E\x32\x2E\x35\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x75\x1A\x69\x09\x00\x00\x02\x00\x31\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF8\x0F\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x10\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x10\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x83\xEC\x08\x48\x8B\x05\x25\x0C\x20\x00\x48\x85\xC0\x74\x05\xE8\x43\x00\x00\x00\x48\x83\xC4\x08\xC3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\x35\x12\x0C\x20\x00\xFF\x25\x14\x0C\x20\x00\x0F\x1F\x40\x00\xFF\x25\x12\x0C\x20\x00\x68\x00\x00\x00\x00\xE9\xE0\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x25\x0A\x0C\x20\x00\x68\x01\x00\x00\x00\xE9\xD0\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x25\xD2\x0B\x20\x00\x66\x90\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x31\xED\x49\x89\xD1\x5E\x48\x89\xE2\x48\x83\xE4\xF0\x50\x54\x49\xC7\xC0\xB0\x05\x40\x00\x48\xC7\xC1\x40\x05\x40\x00\x48\xC7\xC7\x26\x05\x40\x00\xE8\xB7\xFF\xFF\xFF\xF4\x66\x0F\x1F\x44\x00\x00\xB8\x3F\x10\x60\x00\x55\x48\x2D\x38\x10\x60\x00\x48\x83\xF8\x0E\x48\x89\xE5\x76\x1B\xB8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x85\xC0\x74\x11\x5D\xBF\x38\x10\x60\x00\xFF\xE0\x66\x0F\x1F\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x5D\xC3\x0F\x1F\x40\x00\x66\x2E\x0F\x1F\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xBE\x38\x10\x60\x00\x55\x48\x81\xEE\x38\x10\x60\x00\x48\xC1\xFE\x03\x48\x89\xE5\x48\x89\xF0\x48\xC1\xE8\x3F\x48\x01\xC6\x48\xD1\xFE\x74\x15\xB8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x85\xC0\x74\x0B\x5D\xBF\x38\x10\x60\x00\xFF\xE0\x0F\x1F\x00\x5D\xC3\x66\x0F\x1F\x44\x00\x00\x80\x3D\x51\x0B\x20\x00\x00\x75\x11\x55\x48\x89\xE5\xE8\x6E\xFF\xFF\xFF\x5D\xC6\x05\x3E\x0B\x20\x00\x01\xF3\xC3\x0F\x1F\x40\x00\xBF\x20\x0E\x60\x00\x48\x83\x3F\x00\x75\x05\xEB\x93\x0F\x1F\x00\xB8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x85\xC0\x74\xF1\x55\x48\x89\xE5\xFF\xD0\x5D\xE9\x7A\xFF\xFF\xFF\x55\x48\x89\xE5\xBF\xC4\x05\x40\x00\xE8\xCC\xFE\xFF\xFF\xB8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x5D\xC3\x0F\x1F\x44\x00\x00\x41\x57\x41\x56\x41\x89\xFF\x41\x55\x41\x54\x4C\x8D\x25\xBE\x08\x20\x00\x55\x48\x8D\x2D\xBE\x08\x20\x00\x53\x49\x89\xF6\x49\x89\xD5\x4C\x29\xE5\x48\x83\xEC\x08\x48\xC1\xFD\x03\xE8\x57\xFE\xFF\xFF\x48\x85\xED\x74\x20\x31\xDB\x0F\x1F\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x4C\x89\xEA\x4C\x89\xF6\x44\x89\xFF\x41\xFF\x14\xDC\x48\x83\xC3\x01\x48\x39\xEB\x75\xEA\x48\x83\xC4\x08\x5B\x5D\x41\x5C\x41\x5D\x41\x5E\x41\x5F\xC3\x90\x66\x2E\x0F\x1F\x84\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF3\xC3\x00\x00\x48\x83\xEC\x08\x48\x83\xC4\x08\xC3\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x2C\x20\x77\x6F\x72\x6C\x64\x21\x00\x00\x00\x01\x1B\x03\x3B\x30\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x1C\xFE\xFF\xFF\x7C\x00\x00\x00\x5C\xFE\xFF\xFF\x4C\x00\x00\x00\x52\xFF\xFF\xFF\xA4\x00\x00\x00\x6C\xFF\xFF\xFF\xC4\x00\x00\x00\xDC\xFF\xFF\xFF\x0C\x01\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x7A\x52\x00\x01\x78\x10\x01\x1B\x0C\x07\x08\x90\x01\x07\x10\x14\x00\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x08\xFE\xFF\xFF\x2A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x7A\x52\x00\x01\x78\x10\x01\x1B\x0C\x07\x08\x90\x01\x00\x00\x24\x00\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x98\xFD\xFF\xFF\x30\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0E\x10\x46\x0E\x18\x4A\x0F\x0B\x77\x08\x80\x00\x3F\x1A\x3B\x2A\x33\x24\x22\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x44\x00\x00\x00\xA6\xFE\xFF\xFF\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x41\x0E\x10\x86\x02\x43\x0D\x06\x50\x0C\x07\x08\x00\x00\x00\x44\x00\x00\x00\x64\x00\x00\x00\xA0\xFE\xFF\xFF\x65\x00\x00\x00\x00\x42\x0E\x10\x8F\x02\x42\x0E\x18\x8E\x03\x45\x0E\x20\x8D\x04\x42\x0E\x28\x8C\x05\x48\x0E\x30\x86\x06\x48\x0E\x38\x83\x07\x4D\x0E\x40\x72\x0E\x38\x41\x0E\x30\x41\x0E\x28\x42\x0E\x20\x42\x0E\x18\x42\x0E\x10\x42\x0E\x08\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\xAC\x00\x00\x00\xC8\xFE\xFF\xFF\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xE0\x04\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC8\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xB4\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF5\xFE\xFF\x6F\x00\x00\x00\x00\x98\x02\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xB8\x02\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x3D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x30\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x98\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x09\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFE\xFF\xFF\x6F\x00\x00\x00\x00\x60\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\x6F\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF0\xFF\xFF\x6F\x00\x00\x00\x00\x56\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x28\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x04\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x16\x04\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x47\x43\x43\x3A\x20\x28\x55\x62\x75\x6E\x74\x75\x20\x35\x2E\x34\x2E\x30\x2D\x36\x75\x62\x75\x6E\x74\x75\x31\x7E\x31\x36\x2E\x30\x34\x2E\x34\x29\x20\x35\x2E\x34\x2E\x30\x20\x32\x30\x31\x36\x30\x36\x30\x39\x00\x00\x2E\x73\x68\x73\x74\x72\x74\x61\x62\x00\x2E\x69\x6E\x74\x65\x72\x70\x00\x2E\x6E\x6F\x74\x65\x2E\x41\x42\x49\x2D\x74\x61\x67\x00\x2E\x6E\x6F\x74\x65\x2E\x67\x6E\x75\x2E\x62\x75\x69\x6C\x64\x2D\x69\x64\x00\x2E\x67\x6E\x75\x2E\x68\x61\x73\x68\x00\x2E\x64\x79\x6E\x73\x79\x6D\x00\x2E\x64\x79\x6E\x73\x74\x72\x00\x2E\x67\x6E\x75\x2E\x76\x65\x72\x73\x69\x6F\x6E\x00\x2E\x67\x6E\x75\x2E\x76\x65\x72\x73\x69\x6F\x6E\x5F\x72\x00\x2E\x72\x65\x6C\x61\x2E\x64\x79\x6E\x00\x2E\x72\x65\x6C\x61\x2E\x70\x6C\x74\x00\x2E\x69\x6E\x69\x74\x00\x2E\x70\x6C\x74\x2E\x67\x6F\x74\x00\x2E\x74\x65\x78\x74\x00\x2E\x66\x69\x6E\x69\x00\x2E\x72\x6F\x64\x61\x74\x61\x00\x2E\x65\x68\x5F\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x5F\x68\x64\x72\x00\x2E\x65\x68\x5F\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x00\x2E\x69\x6E\x69\x74\x5F\x61\x72\x72\x61\x79\x00\x2E\x66\x69\x6E\x69\x5F\x61\x72\x72\x61\x79\x00\x2E\x6A\x63\x72\x00\x2E\x64\x79\x6E\x61\x6D\x69\x63\x00\x2E\x67\x6F\x74\x2E\x70\x6C\x74\x00\x2E\x64\x61\x74\x61\x00\x2E\x62\x73\x73\x00\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x38\x02\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x38\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x54\x02\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x54\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x21\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x74\x02\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x74\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x24\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x34\x00\x00\x00\xF6\xFF\xFF\x6F\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x98\x02\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x98\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x3E\x00\x00\x00\x0B\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xB8\x02\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xB8\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x46\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x3D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x4E\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\x6F\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x56\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x56\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x5B\x00\x00\x00\xFE\xFF\xFF\x6F\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x60\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x60\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x6A\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x74\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x42\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x98\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x98\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x30\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x7E\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC8\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC8\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x79\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF0\x03\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF0\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x30\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x84\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x04\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8D\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x30\x04\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x30\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x82\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x93\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xB4\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xB4\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x09\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x99\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC0\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC0\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xA1\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD4\x05\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD4\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x34\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xAF\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x06\x40\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF4\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xB9\x00\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xC5\x00\x00\x00\x0F\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD1\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x20\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD6\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x28\x0E\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x28\x0E\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xD0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF8\x0F\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF8\x0F\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xDF\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x28\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xE8\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x28\x10\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x28\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xEE\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x38\x10\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x38\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xF3\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x30\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x38\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x34\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x6C\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFC\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" > binary
chmod +x binary
./binary
```

---

Create your own with

```
cat a.out | hexdump -v -e '"\\\x" 1/1 "%02X" ""' > binaryInHex
echo -n -e "$(cat binaryInHex)" > binary
chmod +x binary
./binary
```

Comment: Can you supply a `SSCCE` to prove your answer? http://sscce.org/

Comment: Hang on, let me print it out and type it into the command line...

Comment: @DarkDestry Done.

Comment: On the one hand I really want to know what your `SSCCE` does, and test it myself.  On the other hand copying random code off the internet and running it on my computer seems like a violation of the spirit of this website...

Comment: @ConorMancone Which is why I did not post a Windows executable and why I initially did not post a `SSCCE`.

Comment: I'll leave it to reverse engineers to **spot the bug**.

Comment: @ConorMancone Try It Online. See edited post.

Comment: Unfortunately, echo on windows is far from that smart. `echo -n -e "win\x00\x20" > file.exe` will actually write ` -n -e "win\x00\x20"` to the file...

Answer (score 1):

Given that Windows comes with PowerShell, you could easily print and type an [Empire](https://github.com/EmpireProject/Empire) payload.
There's quite a few payloads to choose from, including ones designed for privilege escalation, lateral movement, and persistence. 
 The current collections of PowerShell payloads can be found here: 
https://github.com/EmpireProject/Empire/tree/master/lib/modules/powershell

Alternately, you could use [batch scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497133/477563), PowerShell, JScript, or VBA to print arbitrary data, meaning that an executable dropper in those languages would be possible as well.